# Establishing the point-wise convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \frac{\lceil nx\rceil}{n \lceil x \rceil }$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the point-wise limit of this function on the interval $(0, \infty)$ (I know it exists because it is a homework question). I'm having some difficulty with the ceilings. Clearly, whenever x is a natural number, $f_n = 1$, but I am stuck on what to do in other cases. I've tried decoding the ceiling as an infimum (i.e. $\lceil t \rceil = \inf \{m \in {N} : m \geq t\}$, but it hasn't really gotten me farther. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.  For any fixed $x$ we have
$$\frac{nx}{n\lceil x\rceil}\le f_n(x)< \frac{nx+1}{n\lceil x\rceil}\ .$$Now let $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Awesome...I didn't even think about using the squeeze theorem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You always have $nx \le \lceil nx \rceil < nx+1$, so dividing by $n$ gives
$x \le { \lceil nx \rceil \over n} < x+{1 \over n}$. It follows that
$\lim_n { \lceil nx \rceil \over n} = x$.

Hence $f_n(x) \to { x \over \lceil x \rceil}$.